# PG::SyntaxError at /bookmarks - I'm unable to work out why the SQL query is wrong

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error, sinatra, pg

When running my application using sinatra, I get the error message `PG::SyntaxError at /bookmarks
ERROR: syntax error at or near "{" LINE 1: SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {:id=>"5"} ^`
It happens when I click the submit button on `/users/new` route which should then take me to index route `/`.

The backtrace provides the following information

`/Users/BartJudge/Desktop/Makers_2018/bookmark-manager-2019/lib/database_connection.rb in async_exec
    @connection.exec(sql)`

`/Users/BartJudge/Desktop/Makers_2018/bookmark-manager-2019/lib/database_connection.rb in query
    @connection.exec(sql)`

`/Users/BartJudge/Desktop/Makers_2018/bookmark-manager-2019/lib/user.rb in find
    result = DatabaseConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = #{id}")
app.rb in block in <class:BookmarkManager>
    @user = User.find(id: session[:user_id])`

This is the database_connection file

```
require 'pg'

class DatabaseConnection
  def self.setup(dbname)
    @connection = PG.connect(dbname: dbname)
  end

  def self.connection
    @connection
  end

  def self.query(sql)
    @connection.exec(sql)
  end
end
```

This is the user model

```
require_relative './database_connection'
require 'bcrypt'

class User
  def self.create(email:, password:)
    encypted_password = BCrypt::Password.create(password
    )
    result = DatabaseConnection.query("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES('#{email}', '#{encypted_password}') RETURNING id, email;")

    User.new(id: result[0]['id'], email: result[0]['email'])
  end

  attr_reader :id, :email

  def initialize(id:, email:)
    @id = id
    @email = email
  end

  def self.find(id)
    return nil unless id
    result = DatabaseConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = #{id}")
    User.new(
      id: result[0]['id'],
      email: result[0]['email'])
  end
end
```

This is the controller

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require './lib/bookmark'
require './lib/user'
require './database_connection_setup.rb'
require 'uri'
require 'sinatra/flash'
require_relative './lib/tag'
require_relative './lib/bookmark_tag'

class BookmarkManager < Sinatra::Base
  enable :sessions, :method_override
  register Sinatra::Flash

  get '/' do
    "Bookmark Manager"
  end
  get '/bookmarks' do
    @user = User.find(id: session[:user_id])
    @bookmarks = Bookmark.all
    erb :'bookmarks/index'
  end

  post '/bookmarks' do
    flash[:notice] = "You must submit a valid URL" unless     Bookmark.create(url: params[:url], title: params[:title])

    redirect '/bookmarks'
  end

  get '/bookmarks/new' do
    erb :'bookmarks/new'
  end

  delete '/bookmarks/:id' do
    Bookmark.delete(id: params[:id])
    redirect '/bookmarks'
  end

  patch '/bookmarks/:id' do
    Bookmark.update(id: params[:id], title: params[:title], url: params[:url])
    redirect('/bookmarks')
  end

  get '/bookmarks/:id/edit' do
    @bookmark = Bookmark.find(id: params[:id])
    erb :'bookmarks/edit'
  end

  get '/bookmarks/:id/comments/new' do
    @bookmark_id = params[:id]
    erb :'comments/new'
  end

  post '/bookmarks/:id/comments' do
    Comment.create(text: params[:comment], bookmark_id: params[:id])
    redirect '/bookmarks'
  end

  get '/bookmarks/:id/tags/new' do
    @bookmark_id = params[:id]
    erb :'/tags/new'
  end

  post '/bookmarks:id/tags' do
    tag = Tag.create(content: params[:tag])
    BookmarkTag.create(bookmark_id: params[:id], tag_id: tag.id)
    redirect '/bookmarks'
  end

  get '/users/new' do
    erb :'users/new'
  end

  post '/users' do
    user = User.create(email: params[:email], password: params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect '/bookmarks'
  end

  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

self.find(id), in the user model, is where the potentially offending SQL query resides.

I've tried;
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = #{id}"

and "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '#{id}'"

Beyond that, I'm stumped. The query looks fine, but sinatra is having none of it.

Hopefully someone can help me resolve this.
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're call `find` with a hash argument:

```
User.find(id: session[:user_id])
```

but it is expecting just the `id`:

```
class User
  ...
  def self.find(id)
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Then you end up interpolating a hash into your SQL string which results in invalid HTML.

You should be saying:

```
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])
```

to pass in just the `id` that `User.find` expects.

You're also leaving yourself open to SQL injection issues because you're using unprotected string interpolation for your queries rather than placeholders.

Your `query` method should use `exec_params` instead of `exec` and it should take some extra parameters for the placeholder values:

```
class DatabaseConnection
  def self.query(sql, *values)
    @connection.exec_params(sql, values)
  end
end
```

Then things that call `query` should use placeholders in the SQL and pass the values separately:

```
result = DatabaseConnection.query(%q(
  INSERT INTO users (email, password)
  VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING id, email
), email, encypted_password)

result = DatabaseConnection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', id)

...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's sorted out the Sinatra errors. I also had an Rspec error due to the same problem, which I've now just also sorted thanks to your help.